# La traduction d'un mot néerlandais approchant « comprendre », « apprendre »

Tags: traduction, expressions

Ma langue maternelle, le néerlandais, utilise le verbe signifiant littéralement « s’entartrer » dans le sens de comprendre, plus précisément « passer le temps nécessaire afin de comprendre quelque chose ». Il ne s’agit donc pas de comprendre sur-le-champ, mais plutôt de comprendre au compte-gouttes.

En outre, si quelque chose « s’entartre », on ne s’acharne pas à l’apprendre. On voit cette chose au fur et à mesure et on n’essaie pas de l’étudier en détails. L’apprentissage s’appuie notamment sur beaucoup d’exemples. La matière connaît plusieurs facettes auxquelles il faut s’habituer.

D’ailleurs, on emploie ce mot surtout lorsque cette façon d’apprendre est la seule approche efficace, autrement dit si la matière elle-même est trop floue, s'il est inutile de tenter de l’approfondir parce qu’elle est impalpable.

Bien souvent, ce qui « s’entartre » est une pensée mathématique. Je dirais que la tournure peut également s’appliquer à des connaissances, des savoirs, par exemple en matière de langue. Mais un travail d’ordre physique ne « s’entartre » pas ; un geste technique, un « coup de main », non plus.

Je n’ai trouvé nulle part de traduction pour cette tournure. Ai-je bien décrit l’expression ? Ces renseignements vous font-ils penser à un mot français qui conviendrait ici ? Si vous avez quelque chose à me proposer, je suis preneur.

Comment: Quel est le sujet de « s’entartrer » ? Est-ce la personne qui apprend, la matière à apprendre, ou les deux suivant le contexte ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Je pense que le verbe français "s'imprégner" contient les mêmes sous-entendus; on dira par exemple "s'imprégner de la pensée d'un auteur" ou encore "s'imprégner de la langue anglaise". Le verbe peut aussi être utilisé hors du domaine de la connaissance, par exemple "s'imprégner de la beauté d'un lieu".

Son usage dans le cadre des mathématiques semble impliquer une appropriation progressive d'un grand corps de connaissances, plutôt fondé sur des approches et des raisonnements que sur des résultats particuliers.

Il faut sans doute préciser que le verbe, au sens propre, est utilisé pour des liquides : "Une éponge s'imprègne d'eau". La métaphore traduit cette connaissance profonde et progressive.